# Aptana Studio 3 Warning Unescaped Entity

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, aptana

When editing my html-files I often get a warning "Unescaped entity". i.e when writing:  Forename`&nbsp;`Surname without spaces before and after the nonbreaking-space-entity. If I put a space after the semicolon the warning goes away. In this and other cases i.e. with entities for typographic quotes this behaviour of aptana makes absolutely no sense.
How can I stop Aptana from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK is a Tidy fault, and there is no fast solution.
Tidy has some documented problems parsing entities. You can read more about them here:
http://www.htmlpedia.org/wiki/Tidy_3

The only way I know to avoid that warning, is to stop using &nbsp;.
You can replace it with a span tag and a css class:

Instead of:
My&nbsp;nonbreakable&nbsp;phrase.

you can use:
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">My nonbreakable phrase.</span>

or you can put the style inside your css, and use a class instead. BTW, it's the standard way to replace the now discouraged <nobr> tag.

More information about it here:
http://davidwalsh.name/nobr-css

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a Tidy fault. (Tidy doesn't consider `&nbsp;` (etc., etc.) as wrong.)
You can get rid of the strange warnings by using HTML decimal code; so in stead of typing `&nbsp;` you paste `&#160;` .
There are many sites with tables of entities and decimal codes.
References:
[Extended explanation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html)
[One of the many sites with tables with entities](http://www.htmlentities.com/html/entities/)